# How to fill a line graph with a color that changes by slope?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to make a plot that looks like this one (an elevation graph):

[image: Elevation Graph]

Here they're plotting the elevation vs distance, and the region under the graph is colored by the slope (i.e., dElevation/dx). Reds have a positive slope, greens are flat-ish and blues are negative slopes.

If I have x and elevation, it's easy to calculate the slope (dElevation/dx), but I'm stumped how to fill the graph in with a color that changes by slope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mainly using [this approach](http://pradhanphy.blogspot.com/2014/06/filling-between-curves-with-color.html) and adjusting it a little makes this possible:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch

x = np.arange(0,10,0.1)
y = 0.5*np.sin(x)+0.6
grad = np.gradient(y)
elevation_origin = -0.05 # set the zero line until which the color map is filled in. 

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.plot(x, y, label='Elevation')

path = Path(np.array([np.append(x,x[::-1]), np.append(y,np.zeros_like(y))]).T)
patch = PathPatch(path, facecolor='none')
ax.add_patch(patch)
im = plt.imshow(grad.reshape(1,y.size), cmap=plt.cm.jet, interpolation='bicubic',                                        
                extent=[x[0], x[-1], elevation_origin, np.max(y)],aspect='auto',               
                clip_path=patch, clip_on=True)     
plt.show()
```

Of course you can choose different color maps if desired but `jet` should match your example picture. Note that this approach needs to be modified if there are elevations below `elevation_origin`. Please also note that this was possible to find (at least most of it) with a web search.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is perfect. I was trying to do this using `plt.fill_between` but was struggling a bit going down that route. 

Sometimes us noobs don't know the correct terminology to search for (Don't think I posted here without searching first).

Comment: My first attempt included `fill_between` as well :D Many times people do and I just leave a comment but this was not obvious to find, yes. If this answered your question please accept the answer :)

Comment: Read [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/10/16/how-bad-is-your-colormap/) why 'jet' usually isn't an appropriate colormap. In this case, one of the [diverging colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html#diverging) might be more suitable.

Comment: Thanks, I actually might look into this a bit deeper. I never use jet because of aesthetic preference and wasn't aware of the entire internet hating it :D Just adopted from the picture in the question.

Comment: Your answer is certainly a creative interpretation of the linked reference. By the way, `plt.ylim(0, y.max()*1.1)` might help to better position the graph.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to share an alternate version to the answer above.

Instead of:

```
im = plt.imshow(grad.reshape(1,y.size), cmap=plt.cm.jet, interpolation='bicubic',                                        
                extent=[x[0], x[-1], elevation_origin, np.max(y)],aspect='auto',               
                clip_path=patch, clip_on=True)
```

I used:

```
cmap = mpl.cm.bwr
normalize = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=np.min(grad), vmax=np.max(grad))
for i in range(0,100):
    plt.fill_between(x=x[i-1:i+1],y1=y[i-1:i+1],y2=0, color=cmap(normalize(grad[i])))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to solve a similar problem and when I use the plt.imshow approach the gradient isn't right; I think its because my X axis isn't evenly distributed as when I use the plt.fill_between it works correctly.

Can some please explain to me how to change the plt.imhow to work correctly for uneven X axis? As it runs faster and then I can add a colour bar to the edge of the chart.

**Wrong Gradient "Contours" Chart**

```
    im = plt.imshow(grad.reshape(1, y.size), cmap=plt.cm.jet, interpolation='bicubic',
                extent=[x[0], 41, (np.min(y)-(np.std(y)*0.5)), np.max(y)+20], aspect='auto',
                clip_path=patch, clip_on=True)
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

**Right Chart wrong implementation**

```
    cmap = mpl.cm.jet
normalize = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=np.min(grad), vmax=np.max(grad))
for i in range(0,len(x)):
    plt.fill_between(x=x[i - 1:i + 1], y1=y[i - 1:i + 1], y2=0, color=cmap(normalize(grad[i])))
```

[image]